# How to set color from API response in border-color in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am getting `categoryColor` from API Responce and I had set `border-left: 3px solid {{element.categoryColor}}` in inline style. It's working fine and no any other issues in development but in `Visual Studio` appear red in file name as show as below image.

So I want to proper syntax or best practice to apply color in structure using inline style.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular have [attribute binding](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/attribute-class-style-bindings-angular) which should be used in this case.

If I were you i would move everything from `style` to some css class then in this `span` element I would use `[style.borderColor]="element.categoryColor"`

like so:

```css
.some-class {
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    /* ... */
}
```

```html
<span class="some-class" [style.borderColor]="element.categoryColor"></span>
```

but you can use it like so as well:

```html
<span style="border-left: 3px solid transparent;" [style.borderColor]="element.categoryColor"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be using [ngStyle].

`<span [ngStyle]="{ 'border-color': getBorderColor() }">Your content</span>`

And for bordercolor, you could use a function which gets the color code from the api response and that function should return the css syntax, like `2px solid purple`.